# Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I'm using `androidx navigation architecture` along with `Kotlin 1.2.71` in Android studio 3.2.1. My fragment code is:

```
package com.dell.andnav.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.dell.andnav.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome.*


/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [WelcomeFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 *
 */
class WelcomeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        detailButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_welcomeFragment_to_detailsFragment)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = WelcomeFragment()
    }
}
```

And layout code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.WelcomeFragment">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/detailButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/to_detail_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dell.andnav"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        androidExtensions {
            experimental = true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha07"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

When I try to run my code, I get below error:

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
>   public val Activity.detailButton: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome
>   public val Dialog.detailButton: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome
>   public val android.app.Fragment.detailButton: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome
>   public val androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.detailButton: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome
>   public val LayoutContainer.detailButton: Button! defined in kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome

How can I resolve that error?

Comment: why are you mixing support libraries with androidx libraries you should be using either.

Comment: I modified `build.gradle`, please check updated question. Getting same error now

Comment: you should be accessing your view from your fragment `view.detailButton` as it is inside your fragement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Button you are accessing is inside your fragement but your are accessing it directly. You should access it via parent view like we do with java `rootview.findViewById()` so use

```
view.detailButton.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_welcomeFragment_to_detailsFragment)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem with my adapter class and finally problem solved by adding the following code to build.gradle(Module: app) file of the project.

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Since this new version of Kotlin, the Android Extensions have incorporated some new interesting features like caches in any class

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and figured out that the root cause was play-services with versions 17.x.x

**My fix**

Change

> google_android_gms_version

in

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$google_android_gms_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$google_android_gms_version"
```

from **17.x.x** to **15.0.1**
The reason is that play services 17.x.x has dependencies on Androidx

**General way**
Click the Gradle option in the extreme right panel,
Go to app -> help ->dependencies
Search androidx in the chart. Find out which library has it. Change or modify your gradle accordingly.

Those who can migrate to androidx, that well and good. If you have to keep it at appcompat, then follow the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have two issues with this error.

1. I mixed receiver type in extension.

   ```
   import android.widget.Toolbar

   fun Toolbar.setMenuItem() : Boolean {
       ...
   }
   ```

Then tried to apply this function to `Toolbar` in a layout. But in XML it was `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.

2. This function led to the error:

   ```
   private fun showProgress(view: View? = null) {
       (view?.progressBar ?: progressBar)?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }
   ```

Android Studio offered layouts that contained `progressBar`, and I chose one. But `view?.progressBar` continued to be red. Then I shortened a header:

`private fun showProgress(view: View)`.

Only after that AS offered layouts. Then I again wrote: `private fun showProgress(view: View? = null)`.

Answer (score 0):

With androidx, you have to access with itemView

```
itemView.detailButton
```

import .view.* like below

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome.view.*
```

instead of

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_welcome.*
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, maybe it's not the answer you want hear but I had implements duplicated, just let one and did works for me